# Is it possible to exclude an artifact from being mirrored when using multi stage nexus repositories

Tags: maven, nexus

My scenario is this: I have 2 nexus, let's say A and B. A is specific to my team, whereas B is a shared nexus between multiple teams.
A mirrors B.
Now B has about 20 different projects. I want A to mirror B for 19 of those projects, but not for the remaining 1. Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: Any specific reasons you want that one? Just to save space on the disk?

Comment: How are you mirroring?  Proxy?